# Xargs and bash script

Tags: bash, xargs

The script works fine when executed manually but I recived the folloing error while it's run as a cron job: `xargs: postsuper: No such file or directory`

```
#!/bin/bash

mailgueue=$(mailq | awk '/MAILER-DAEMON/ { print $1 }' | wc -l)

if [ $mailgueue -ge 1 ]
    then
/usr/bin/mailq | awk '/MAILER-DAEMON/ { print $1 }' | xargs -n 1 postsuper -d

fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide the full path to postsuper in your script.  It's probably just not in cron's $PATH.

Comment: It didn't help however I just completely removed the xargs command and it works fine.